# i want to translate image from left to right in a circular motion but its leaving white background

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

This is my anim file am using for left to right animation

```
<translate
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fromXDelta="0%p"
android:toXDelta="100%p"
android:duration="2000"
android:startOffset="0"
android:repeatCount="infinite"
android:repeatMode="restart"/>
```

but the problem is its leaving blank white space behind animation and i want to be filled by the portion on image going out of display at right side.[image]

This is the image that am using.
So, acc. to image if blue color is animating from left to right then that blue should be visible at left side before grey color.

Comment: It would be a good idea to do some kind of a fiddle if you could. That being said - you have to think about doing animation like if you were painting on a canvas.  Every time you start the next frame it is a brand new canvas.  So you always have to fill in the background part first, before you do the foreground part.  It sounds like you are not doing the background part first and that is why what you get has white around it.